# How do I update Spyder when terminal command results in "All requested packages already installed"?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I've been trying to update Spyder, which is currently version 4.0.1. I first updated Anaconda using

```
conda update anaconda
```

which updated Anaconda to version 4.9.0. I then tried to update Spyder with the following

```
conda update spyder
```

but this resulted in "All requested packages already installed." and the version remained 4.0.1. I tried updating through the Anaconda Navigator GUI, but when I click the gear icon on Spyder, it shows https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j6oM.png with "Update application" grayed out.

Every time I open Spyder, it tells me that version 4.1.15 exists, but I'm not really sure what to do.

Edit: answer is below in the comments. Of note, I may have tried the direct install command before but wrote 4.1.**15** instead of 4.1.**5** because I misread the latest version number.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I think instead of running `conda update anaconda`, you ran instead `conda update conda` (and both things are not the same). I'm mentioning that because you said above `which updated Anaconda to version 4.9.0`. However, there's no 4.9.0 version of Anaconda (its versions are `2020.07`, `2020.02`, `custom`, etc); but there's a `4.9.0` version of `conda`. Please be sure of running `conda update anaconda` (which should update a bunch of packages), and then run `conda install spyder=4.1.5` to get our latest version.

Comment: So I wrote conda update anaconda, but you're right that when I tried to find the version, I wrote conda --version. When I wrote anaconda --version, my terminal output was: anaconda Command line client (version 1.7.2). That still doesn't match the version format you described above so I'm a bit unsure

Comment: What's the output of `conda list anaconda`?

Comment: Trying to make this look better 

# packages in environment at /Users/username/opt/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2020.07                  py37_0  
anaconda                  custom                   py37_1  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.10.0                   py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0

Comment: Ok, that looks right. Now what happens if you run `conda install spyder=4.1.5`?

Comment: Yep, there we go. It initially said it failed with a frozen solve and had to use a flexible solve. Unsure what that means, but figured I'd mention it. Either way, it appears to be working. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: No problem and glad you were finally able to update Spyder!